# How to backup original firmware and personal data before firmware change?

Tags: backup, 2.1-eclair, device-firmware

Before I try a custom-built firmware, I would like to backup the original one from my 2.1 SE Xperia phone. I know some original firmwares are out there to download but I would trust my own one better. How can the original firmware be backed up?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @ZnewmaN yes it is rooted.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) [tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), which already gives you some "first-aid" advice. Take a closer look at the *Nandroid* section, as that is what you will need:

First, you will need to install a custom recovery (see e.g. [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode)). The most common choice here is [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod), as it is available for most devices. Depending on your device, there might be other choices available. For your Xperia, there probably is no [Amon Ra Recovery](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Amon_Ra_recovery_tool) (which is very similar to already mentioned *ClockworkMod* recovery), but there might be e.g. [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp). This custom recovery will replace your stock-recovery, and add some useful functionality -- one of the new features being [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backups. Your [device-firmware](/questions/tagged/device-firmware) will remain untouched when you flash the custom recovery.

Once you've installed the custom recovery, you can boot into it with a special combination of keys. On most devices, you need to hold the <kbd>Vol -</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> keys pressed simultaneously on boot, until the recovery menu appears -- but that key combination might differ for your device (and the custom recovery chosen). Check the documentation/readme/hints where you downloaded your recovery.

Bootet into the recovery, there will be a menu item for backup (it may be labeled "Backup" or "Nandroid" or "Nandroid Backup", but you will unmistakenly identify it). Here you can create (or restore) a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup, which includes an image for each of your device's partitions (i.e. all that would be touched/changed when flashing another [device-firmware](/questions/tagged/device-firmware); it will, however, *not* backup/restore your device's [radio-firmware](/questions/tagged/radio-firmware)).

[image: ClockworkMod Backup] [image: ClockworkMod Menu]
<sup>Examples of ClockworkMod (source: [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/clockworkmod-recovery-beta-released-for-moto-razr-i/), [LaptoppMag](http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-root-and-install-android-2-2-froyo-on-the-htc-droid-incredible/clockwork-mod-boot-screen))</sup>

The screenshots show you the ClockworkMod menu of two different versions (I marked the entry you will need to create/restore backups). The first screenshot shows a complete Nandroid backup being made, and you can see in the light-gray test all the "Backing up" lines, indicating each backed-up partition.

Having created such a *Nandroid Backup*, you can return to this state of your [device-firmware](/questions/tagged/device-firmware) anytime. It would also include your apps and data; so if you don't like the custom ROM you've tried, simply boot into your custom recovery, and restore your backup.